# Change Content of Target Div on Slide Change

Tags: jquery, slider, fullpage.js

JQuery ubernoob here. I'm trying to get the text of an active slide into a target div to achieve something similar to this.

http://www.davidchipperfield.co.uk/project/valentino_new_york

I'm using Alvaro Trigo's [fullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) multi page slider and would like to be able to update the caption in a separate div with each slide change. I've successfully used .appendTo by finding the active class to grab a current div and display its contents in the target div but it only works once. I feel like I'm close but could really use a little help here. Do I need to use .empty() after each slide leave? It looks like the slider already assigns an active class to the current slide which may or may not make my life easier. Or am I way off and is there a better way to do this?

This is what I've got so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#fullpage').fullpage({ slidesNavigation: true, css3:true,   slidesNavigation: false,
    afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor,   slideIndex){
                $('.slide.active p').each(function(){
                $(this).appendTo('#current-caption');
                });

            }});
});

<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="slow-fade" data-stellar-ratio=".7">
          <div class="small-centered medium-centered large-centered     large-12 columns">
                  <h1>Portfolio</h1>
                  <h2>A selection of recent works.</h2>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- section -->
<div class="section">Some section
  <div class="slide"><div class="caption active"><p>First Caption</p></div></div>
  <div class="slide"><div class="caption"><p>Second Caption</p></div></div>
  <div class="slide"><div class="caption"><p>Third Caption</p></div></div>
  <div class="slide"><div class="caption"><p>and the 4th</p></div></div>
</div> <!-- section -->
<div class="section">Some section</div> <!-- section -->
<div class="section">Some section</div> <!-- section -->
</div>

<footer class="portfolio-footer">
<div class="footer-nav">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="large-3 columns">
                    <div id="current-caption"></div>
            </div><!--large-3-->
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                    <p> 1/5 </p>
            </div><!--large-6-->
            <div class="large-3 columns">
                    <p> Read More </p>
            </div><!--large-6-->
    </div><!--row-->
</div>
</div><!-- footer-nav -->
</footer><!-- portfolio-nav -->
```

Comment: try going with `each()` through the all slides and finding `active` there;  `$('.slide').each( function() { if($(this).hasClass('active')) { // do smth; } })`

Comment: @MancharyManchaary Thanks. Still not quite there although this has allowed me to assign an active class to the .caption which I haven't been able to do till now. So close! Am I just missing something simple here?

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({ slidesNavigation: true, css3:true,     slidesNavigation: false,
        afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){
     $('.slide').each(function(){
     if($(this).hasClass('active'))
     $('.caption.active').appendTo('#current-caption');
     });

    }});
});`

Comment: Try `var get_html = $(this).find(".caption").html (); $("#current-caption").html(get_html); or .append(get_html);`and try to console log the `get_html` var to see if its working right

Comment: @MancharyManchaary You are a javascript god! Thank you so much.

Comment: you are welcome. I will make it an answer for other users with the same question

Answer (score 0):

Go with `each()` through the `.slide`s and find it `caption` to append it to the `#current-caption`

```
 $('.slide').each(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('active')) { // find out if it is active slide;
        var get_html = $(this).find(".caption").html(); // get active slide caption text/html
        $("#current-caption").html(get_html); // do something with it
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what's your problem. Ideally you should provide a reproduction in jsfiddle or codepen.

But I would go for something like this:

```
afterSlideLoad: function (anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {
     $(this).find('p').appendTo('#current-caption');
}
```

Take into account that `$(this)` inside the callback makes reference to the active slide as show [in the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterslideload-anchorlink-index-slideanchor-slideindex):

```
var loadedSlide = $(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

See this jsfiddle to see the full code for how I am creating a fixed footer with fullPage.js where information from each slide (in the form of html) populates three fields in the footer with both section changes and slide changes.

https://jsfiddle.net/poweredbydinoflesh/qww1kL3v/3/

```
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="slow-fade" data-stellar-ratio=".7">
         <div class="caption"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
         <div class="page-number"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
          <div class="small-centered medium-centered large-centered        large-12 columns">
                  <h1>Portfolio</h1>
                  <h2>A selection of recent works.</h2>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- section -->
<div class="section">Some section
  <div class="slide"><div class="caption"><p>first caption</p></div>       
<div class="page-number"><p>Lorem ipsum amet principurum</p></div></div>
  <div class="slide"><div class="caption"><p>Second Caption</p></div>    
 <div class="page-number"><p>1/3</p></div></div>
  <div class="slide"><div class="caption"><p>Third Caption</p></div>
 <div class="page-number"><p>2/3</p></div></div>
  <div class="slide"><div class="caption"><p>and the 4th</p></div>
  <div class="page-number"><p>3/3</p></div></div>
</div> <!-- section -->
<div class="section">Some section
  <div class="slide"><div class="caption"><p>1st in Second</p></div>  
  <div class="page-number"><p>Chlorum dolor und losicious</p></div></div>
  <div class="slide"><div class="caption"><p>2nd in the new sec</p></div><div class="page-number"><p>1/3</p></div></div>
  <div class="slide"><div class="caption"><p>3rd in sec</p></div><div class="page-number"><p>2/3</p></div></div>
  <div class="slide"><div class="caption"><p>BOOYA!</p></div><div class="page-number"><p>3/3</p></div></div>
</div> <!-- section -->
<div class="section">Some section
  <div class="slide"><div class="caption"><p>1st in 3rd section</p></div><div class="page-number"><p>&nbsp;</p></div></div>
  <div class="slide"><div class="caption"><p>2nd in 3rd</p></div><div class="page-number"><p>1/2</p></div></div>
</div> <!-- section -->
 </div>
<footer class="portfolio-footer">
<div class="footer-nav">
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-3 columns">
    <div class="current-caption"></div>
  </div><!--large-3-->
 <div class="large-6 columns">
    <div class="current-page"></div>
 </div><!--large-6-->
 <div class="large-3 columns">
    <p> Read More </p>
 </div><!--large-3-->
 </div><!--row-->
 </div>
 </div><!-- footer-nav -->
 </footer><!-- portfolio-nav -->

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#fullpage').fullpage({ slidesNavigation: true, css3:true, slidesNavigation: false,
        onLeave: function(index, newIndex, direction){
                if (index == 0 && direction == 'down'){
                    var section_html = $(this).next().find(".caption").html ();
                    $(".current-caption").html(section_html);
                    var section_html = $(this).prev().find(".page-number").html ();
                    $(".current-page").html(section_html);
                }
                else if(index == 1 && direction == 'down'){
                    var section_html = $(this).next().find(".caption").html ();
                    $(".current-caption").html(section_html);
                    var section_html = $(this).next().find(".page-number").html ();
                    $(".current-page").html(section_html);
                }
                else if(index == 2 && direction == 'down'){
                    var section_html = $(this).next().find(".caption").html ();
                    $(".current-caption").html(section_html);
                    var section_html = $(this).next().find(".page-number").html ();
                    $(".current-page").html(section_html);
                }
                else if(index == 3 && direction == 'down'){
                    var section_html = $(this).next().find(".caption").html ();
                    $(".current-caption").html(section_html);
                    var section_html = $(this).next().find(".page-number").html ();
                    $(".current-page").html(section_html);
                }
                else if (index == 4 && direction == 'up'){
                    var section_html = $(this).prev().find(".caption").html ();
                    $(".current-caption").html(section_html);
                    var section_html = $(this).prev().find(".page-number").html ();
                    $(".current-page").html(section_html);
                }
                else if(index == 3 && direction == 'up'){
                    var section_html = $(this).prev().find(".caption").html ();
                    $(".current-caption").html(section_html);
                    var section_html = $(this).prev().find(".page-number").html ();
                    $(".current-page").html(section_html);
                }
                else if(index == 2 && direction == 'up'){
                    var section_html = $(this).prev().find(".caption").html ();
                    $(".current-caption").html(section_html);
                    var section_html = $(this).prev().find(".page-number").html ();
                    $(".current-page").html(section_html);
                }
            },
     afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){
                                    var get_html = $(this).find(".caption").html ();
                                    $(".current-caption").html(get_html);
                                    var get_html = $(this).find(".page-number").html ();
                                    $(".current-page").html(get_html);
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

- Huge thank you to @mancharymanchaary for helping me execute this code with the correct direction and to @alvaro for an amazing plugin and for bringing attention to the role of $(this)

** I am positive I am probably doing this in a much less efficient way than I could but I'm new to jQuery so would love to know how I can do this better. Any and all ideas are welcome.