# Automatically copy text from one div and replace the text in an other div with fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

For my portfolio, I’m building a new site with [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js). My aim is to combine the data-anchor with a script, that copy some hidden text at each slide (.caption), and replace it into an other slide (.current-caption), when the slide is loaded. Ideally it should work both vertically and horizontally (sections and slides), although my initial portfolio is horizontal only. I’m using afterSlideLoad for the slides, and I have read, that the afterLoad is necessary for the first slide/section.

I have looked at this solution: [Change Content of Target Div on Slide Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33591312/change-content-of-target-div-on-slide-change) – but it doesn’t work. I guess that fullpage.js has changed significantly since 2015, or something els is wrong.

I have very little js/jquery programming skills and will appreciate very much, if someone could help me out by making my JSFiddle work, both horizontal and vertical – and thereby helping others to.

I got this so far (also see my JSFiddle below):

```
<div class="current-caption"><p>.current-caption</p></div>

<div id="fullpage">

    <div class="section" data-anchor="S1" style="background-color: #ddd;"> 
                    
        <div class="slide" data-anchor="S1s1">
            <h1>S1s1</h1>
            <div class="caption"><p>Caption text for S1s1</p></div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="slide" data-anchor="S1s2">
            <h1>S1s2</h1>
            <div class="caption"><p>Caption text for S1s2</p></div>
        </div>

    </div> 
    
    <div class="section" data-anchor="S2" style="background-color: #fff;"> 
        
        <div class="slide" data-anchor="S2s1">
            <h1>S2s1</h1>
            <div class="caption"><p>Caption text for S2s1</p></div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="slide" data-anchor="S2s2">
            <h1>S2s2</h1>
            <div class="caption"><p>Caption text for S2s2</p></div>
        </div>

    </div> 
    
</div> 

var myFullpage = new fullpage('#fullpage', {
    verticalCentered: true,
    autoScrolling: true,
    controlArrows: true,
    
    afterSlideLoad: function(section, origin, destination, direction){
        var slide_html = $(this).find(".caption").html ();
        $(".current-caption").html(slide_html); 
    },  
            
    afterLoad: function(origin, destination, direction){
        var section_html = $(this).find(".caption").html ();
        $(".current-caption").html(section_html); 
    }
});
```

My JSFiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/JorgenB/x78qo2f9/16

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 var slide_html = $(destination.item).find(".caption").text();
 $(".current-caption").text(slide_html);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/hspo65v9/11/

Comment: Right before I hit the post button with the exact same answer :-)

Comment: Hi T J - thanks a lot! Looks good and at first glans also works right. But after a few left and right, up and down, it starts to go wrong, with the wrong text. The page name e.g. S2s2 should go in the .current-caption. I'm not clever enough to figure out whats wrong..?

Comment: If possible, cold you please show me how to include the styling from the caption div as well, e.g.: <p>..and any <i>styling</i> in between the paragraph</p>?